# Post function is not working in php

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm just a beginner on php and learning how to code. I'm following a cbt nugget where I'm already on a an action to post the inserted value on a form and pass it to action page and insert to database. I getting this message when I try on the submit button

0Problems with query:

My DB connector

```
<?php

 $host = "localhost";
 $user = "root";
 $password = "";
 $db = "linuxcbtcontacts";

 # Step 1 instantiate DB object
 $conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,"",$db) or die("Problems connecting:" .      mysql_error());
 #if ($conn) { echo "True"; }

 #$dbselect = mysqli_select_db("linuxcbtcontacts", $conn) or die("Error selecting DB:" . mysql_error());

 # Step 2 - select DB
 #$dbselect = mysqli_select_db($conn, "linuxcbtcontacts") or die("Error selecting DB:" . mysql_error());
 $dbselect = mysqli_select_db($conn,$db) or die("Error selecting DB:" .   mysql_error());

 ?>
```

My form action page (after hitting the submit from the form)

```
<?php
require 'dbconnect.php';


$unique_check = "select name from contacts where name = 'name'";
$results_unique_check = mysqli_query($conn,$unique_check);
$rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($results_unique_check);
echo $rowcount;

if ($rowcount > 0) {
echo "Please use in different name", "<br>";
echo "<a href=query2.php>go back</a>";
exit(); }
else {
$query1 = "INSERT INTO   contacts(name,email,age,yearborn,ratesite,industry,buyourproducts,software,hardware)    VALUES('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[age]','$_POST[yearborn]','$_POST[ratesite]','$_POST[industry]','$_POST[buyourproducts],'$_POST[software]','$_POST[hardware]')";

# Step 3 - invoke query
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$query1) or die("Problems with query:" . mysql_error());

 $rowcount = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
 echo "Total Inserted Records:\t", $rowcount, "<br>";

 }


 ?>
```

From the cbt I should get this message after the submit button was clicked

```
0Total Inserted Records:1
```

Already tweaked on all possibilities on what I saw on the internet but still i end on the "0Problems with query:" message

Comment: You can't mix and match `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: Change `VALUES('$_POST[name]',..` to `VALUES('".$_POST['name']."',` for all POST values

Comment: @NanaPartykar What difference are you trying to say that will make?

Comment: Thanks Nana Partykar  your suggestion worked after I changed it.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Will do @tadman, I'm just a beginner and starting to learn from php, your advise is noted.

Comment: @AppsTester Exactly why I'm mentioning it. The sooner you keep these things in mind, the better, it avoids a lot of ugly surprises in the future. Plus, using placeholder values all but eliminates quoting errors and that will save you considerable time.

Comment: @AppsTester For reference, that isn't what fixed it, you just fixed it accidentally while making the changes. `'$_POST[buyourproducts]` <-- missing quote.

Comment: Still Need To Say *The Difference* @JonStirling?

Comment: @AppsTester: Glad to hear. *Keep Coding.*

Comment: @NanaPartykar It was rhetorical. Your suggestion makes zero difference.

Comment: No Problem @JonStirling. OP Solved His Problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
  $query1 = "INSERT INTO   contacts(name,email,age,yearborn,ratesite,industry,buyourproducts,software,hardware)    VALUES('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['age']."','".$_POST['yearborn']."','".$_POST['ratesite']."','".$_POST['industry']."','".$_POST['buyourproducts']."','".$_POST['software']."','".$_POST['hardware']."')";
```

Comment: What difference are you saying that will make?

Comment: @JonStirling it single quotes the array field names (which is what the actual problem seems to be). However this is a terrible terrible way to do this as it is open to SQL injection.

Comment: @JonStirling I can't run that. `Unexpected T_ECAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING` line 13

Comment: @apokryfos It's already run. You can see the output of both one after the other...

Comment: @apokryfos Hell, run it through your own PHP interpreter. :P

Comment: Never said it was pretty, but it certainly isn't "wrong" :)